# YouTube playlists no longer auto-play. How is this error fixed?

Tags: youtube, google-chrome, youtube-playlist, autoplay

So when a video in a playlist ends it just stops and displays the thumbnail image and the play button. I opened up the console and notice that win the video ends I get:

```
[Deprecation] HTML Imports is deprecated and will be removed in M73, around March 2019. Please use ES modules instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5144752345317376 for more details.

22:35:06.982 desktop_polymer_sel_auto_svg_home_v2.js:1557 <link rel=preload> must have a valid `as` value
e @ desktop_polymer_sel_auto_svg_home_v2.js:1557

22:35:09.196 network.js:15 [Deprecation] chrome.loadTimes() is deprecated, instead use standardized API: nextHopProtocol in Navigation Timing 2. https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5637885046816768.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at HTMLElement.setPlaylistComponent (desktop_polymer_sel_auto_svg_home_v2.js:14132)
    at HTMLElement.attached (desktop_polymer_sel_auto_svg_home_v2.js:12683)
    at HTMLElement.e.attached (desktop_polymer_sel_auto_svg_home_v2.js:7728)
    at HTMLElement.a.connectedCallback (desktop_polymer_sel_auto_svg_home_v2.js:7660)
    at uh (desktop_polymer_sel_auto_svg_home_v2.js:738)
    at HTMLElement.isTwoColumnsChanged_ (desktop_polymer_sel_auto_svg_home_v2.js:11919)
    at Object.nU [as fn] (desktop_polymer_sel_auto_svg_home_v2.js:7208)
    at lU (desktop_polymer_sel_auto_svg_home_v2.js:7206)
    at kU (desktop_polymer_sel_auto_svg_home_v2.js:7205)
    at HTMLElement.a._propertiesChanged (desktop_polymer_sel_auto_svg_home_v2.js:7258)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have lots of music playlists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed by removing all google and youtube cookies and reloading the browser.